# SVCutil.exe enable support for Datetimeoffset

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, svcutil.exe

I have a proxy class generated by svcutil.exe for wcf based service. It uses the DateTime type for xsd:datetime field. DateTime converts the date to UTC if offset is provided and I loose the actual local date.

`var date = DateTime.Parse("2022-05-29T21:55:00.000-07:00"); date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");`

gives me the date as 30 and i need to get the date as 29.

I have looked into the svcutil documentation to enable support for DateTimeOffset but I can not get it to work with \tcv:Version35 or \async switch.

Please note that the message received by my service get automatically de-serialized to the object model generated by svcutil.

Comment: WCF already works with DateTimeOffset. The question you posted doesn't use that type though, it uses `DateTime` which *doesn't* support offsets or timezones. It can only be Local, UTC or Unknown. Even if the string has an offset, the resulting value can only be UTC, Local or Unknown. Obviously `date` doesn't have the value you expected

Comment: It uses DateTime because that's what gets generated in the proxy classes by svcutil. If I could get the svcutil to generate the DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime and this object model could be filled when receiving the message and deserialization, I think my problem will be solved.